How does star grounding work when you include a chassis and multiple PCBs?
I am just wiring a project and I was wondering how the star topology for LV grounding works when using a chassis GND as well. I have a metal enclosure which houses a few electronic boards. One master and a few other boards that are powered by 12 V outputs from the master through HS switches.
Should I connect my bench top power supply negative straight to a chassis point as it enters the enclosure? I then take my master board's negative supply from this point rather than the connector coming in and also have the other few boards that are powered by the master to also have their GND straight to this single chassis GND stud. Does this sound right?
Should I instead have the other boards that are powered by the master's 12 V to get their GND through the master as well? I wasn't sure if this would cause ground loops.
Alternatively, do I go straight from panel connector to master board for the neg and splice that to the GND point?
All circuits are DC and no sensitive or high frequency stuff happening. The master will have control of a few contactors which will pull 5 A for a maximum of 300 ms so I want to stop that causing ground loop issues as well.
EDIT: Some quick sketches to show what I mean. The current would not travel through the chassis but all GNDs would go to the stud on the chassis and back up the from the PSU 0v line:



In general, you want to keep chassis and power returns separate.  So in your case, you want a 12V rail (supply), and 12V return (signal return).  You do not want your chassis to carry any return current.  At some point, you probably need to connect the chassis to 12V return.  Where this happens depends on the complexity of your system.

Ground conductors should not carry normal load currents; they are designed to return fault current to the source and dissipate it in the event of a spike in energy, such as a lightning strike or power surge.
So, what do you call voltages and currents on your ground conductors? Noise and unsafe. Imagine applying direct current (DC) through the building steel, aircraft structures, and ships' superstructures—and the galvanic corrosion that results. People frown when wings fall off planes or when buildings fall.

Hey @SteveSh , so a stud on the chassis shouldn’t be the center star point, it should be 1 of the spurs of a different center star point? I’ll draw out what I am thinking in the morning and upload. I appreciate the thoughts!

@Matt -  Yes, a sketch would help a lot.

@SteveSh I have added some quick thoughts to the OP, thanks!

@Matt - You want to use the option shown in the 2nd sketch.  You want the power supple and return line to be in close proximity, right next to each other.

Hi @SteveSh Ok thank you! So everything including contactors connected through the maters GND plane which then goes out to the PSU and splice to chassis

@Matt - Except that you may want to consider making the return/chassis connection back at the PSU.  But I guess what you have shown is OK so long as the PSU is floating, and there aren't any other loads on the PSU.

@SteveSh So nothing internal to the enclosure going to chassis, only the PSU externally?

@Matt - I think either approach is OK, so long as what you've shown is the only load on your PSU.

@SteveSh There will be a few of these enclosures all duplicated from the same supply

So then you want the PSU return to be connected to chassis/structure/GND at the PSU.  One place only.

Summary:
The star point ought to be the lowest impedance for DC distribution and the lowest impedance point for AC shielding and ESD bypass.
Rack mounted systems will extend chassis ground but the circuits should not intentionally use chassis ground for loads.   Some loads such as in car chassis are an exception.
When the case is PE stud grounded and the DC 0V is also grounded, this causes HIPOT testing to stress all the components from AC to DC via the leakage C and the lowest capacitance spots will get the highest voltage.
Details:
Since ground is defined as 0V, any deviation in voltage, known as "ground shift", can significantly impact system performance. Ground shift contributes to supply ripple in PSRR (Power Supply Rejection Ratio) measurements and combines with DC voltage drops to distort accuracy and stability.
The Importance of Star Ground Connections
To mitigate ground shift, reduce noise, and ensure reliable operation, Star Grounding is essential. A Star Ground topology centralizes all return currents at a single low-impedance point. This prevents multiple ground paths from interacting, which can otherwise cause:
•   Voltage drops across shared ground paths, leading to unwanted cross-talk and errors.
•   Ground loops, which introduce noise and oscillations in sensitive circuits.
•   Increased EMI (Electromagnetic Interference), particularly in mixed-signal systems.
In a Star Ground system:

Analog Ground: Sensitive, low-noise applications (e.g., sensors and amplifiers) have their own clean return path.
Digital Ground: High-speed switching circuits are isolated to minimize noise coupling to analog circuits.
Power Ground: Heavy load currents are separated to avoid contaminating low-level signal grounds.
By isolating each return path and converging them at the Star Center (the point of lowest impedance), you effectively minimize voltage differences between various ground domains, ensuring stable operation across the system.

Practical Grounding and EMC Considerations
•   PE Ground: The Protective Earth (PE) ground from the grid outlet must not carry load currents. Its role is strictly limited to safety, ESD bypassing, and EMC suppression through components like Y-capacitor snubbers and TVS diodes.
•   DC Ground: The DC return ground serves multiple purposes but should connect to the PE ground only at a well-defined point, often at the chassis. This prevents stray currents and ESD from creating voltage stress across isolation barriers, particularly in systems using small isolation transformers.
Reducing Inductance and Noise in Star Grounds
Ground shift and noise are further reduced by minimizing parasitic inductance in the ground paths. To achieve this:
•   Use Litz wire or flat braid wire to reduce high-frequency inductance.
•   Keep the Length/Width ratio of ground conductors low, as inductance increases logarithmically with this ratio. A practical low-inductance path can achieve: L∼0.25 nH/cm  Differential paths can reduce this somewhat.
•   Knowing the maximum rate of change in current (dI/dtdI/dtdI/dt), you can estimate the voltage noise introduced by ground inductance: V=L*dI/dt
Managing Capacitor Effects Near the Load
Low ESR capacitors are effective at minimizing voltage ripple but can inadvertently create high-Q resonances. To suppress these resonances, a ferrite choke may be required in series to dampen common-mode noise. Without proper capacitor placement near the load, conducted RF emissions can radiate through power cables, compromising EMC compliance.
The response time (τ) of a low ESR capacitor, defined as:
τ=ESR×C  can be less than 1us but typically < 20 us with std. e-caps 10x higher.
This determines the bandwidth for filtering noise, where the half-power bandwidth (f−3dB) is:
f{-3dB} =  0.5/  τ  (0 to 63% step response)
Conclusion
Adopting a Star Ground topology is critical for minimizing ground shift, managing noise, and ensuring system stability. By centralizing return paths and controlling impedance, you prevent voltage drops, ground loops, and EMI issues. This approach is especially valuable in mixed-signal systems, where analog precision and digital noise must coexist without interference.

Hey @D.A.S , thanks for the in depth response. I have added some images to what I am thinking above. As for power GND my master has 3 CAN busses, MCU and 4 contactor drives that all share a common GND plane (Both inner layers of PCB). As the contactors are 5A for <300ms before settiling at 0.5A is this ok to share a GND plane through the master or should the contactors be tied to the star point instead? Thanks!

It depends on your noise tolerances to $I^2R$
